# Grouping and summing in LINQ to XML

Tags: linq-to-xml

Given the XML below, I need to group by InputItem and sum the costs for all years. So the results should be:

1. Research Contracts, 7000
2. Technical Contracts, 5000
3. Hospitality,  2000

Here's the XML:

```
<Inputs>
    <Inputs_Table_Row>
        <InputItem>Research Contracts</InputItem>
        <TotalYear1>1000</TotalYear1>
        <TotalYear2>2000</TotalYear2>
    </Inputs_Table_Row>
    <Inputs_Table_Row>
        <InputItem>Research Contracts</InputItem>
        <TotalYear1>2000</TotalYear1>
        <TotalYear2>2000</TotalYear2>
    </Inputs_Table_Row>
    <Inputs_Table_Row>
        <InputItem>Technical Contracts</InputItem>
        <TotalYear1>1000</TotalYear1>
        <TotalYear2>2000</TotalYear2>
    </Inputs_Table_Row>
    <Inputs_Table_Row>
        <InputItem>Technical Contracts</InputItem>
        <TotalYear1>1000</TotalYear1>
        <TotalYear2>1000</TotalYear2>
    </Inputs_Table_Row>
    <Inputs_Table_Row>
        <InputItem>Hospitality</InputItem>
        <TotalYear1>1000</TotalYear1>
        <TotalYear2>1000</TotalYear2>
    </Inputs_Table_Row>
</Inputs>
```

Here's my attempt simply to group so far, but I had no success:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\CrpTotalsSimple.xml");

var query = from c in doc.Descendants("Inputs_Table_Row")
            group new
            {
                Item = (string)c.Element("InputItem")
            }
            by c.Element("InputItem")
            into groupedData

            select new
            {
                ItemName = groupedData.Key.Value
            };

foreach (var item in query)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Item: {0}", item.ItemName));
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I was just missing using Value on the group by clause. Here's my working solution:

```
var query = from c in doc.Descendants("Inputs_Table_Row")
group new
{
    Item = c.Element("InputItem").Value,
    ItemValue = (int)c.Element("TotalYear1") + (int)c.Element("TotalYear2")
 }
 by c.Element("InputItem").Value 
 into groupedData

 select new
 {
      ItemName = groupedData.Key,
      ItemTotal = groupedData.Sum(rec => rec.ItemValue)
  };
```

Comment: BTW, I got help from this article:
http://blog.blocks4.net/post/2007/08/Querying-XML-documents-with-LINQ-to-XML.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You need something like...

```
var query = from yearTotalEl in doc.Descendants()
            where yearTotalEl.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("TotalYear")
            group (decimal)yearTotalEl 
            by (string)yearTotalEl.Parent.Element("InputItem") into g
            select new {ItemName = g.Key, Sum = g.Sum()};
```

I'm using `decimal` because I suspect you're dealing with a currency that may have a fractional component - `int` would otherwise be fine.